# Cloudberry sync of modified files

Tags: amazon-s3, cloudberry

I'm using the free version of Cloudberry to sync my AWS S3 buckets, but modified files of the same name do not seem to transfer. Is this possible with the commercial version of Cloudberry? I see reference to comparing MD5 hash for files that's grayed out. Is this going to allow me to replace modified files during sync?

Comment: Have you asked Cloudberry? The Pro version has a 15 day trial, too.

Comment: CloudBerry Explorer or CloudBerry Backup? I find with CloudBerry backup it picks up files that have changed or files that have their modification date changed and uploads them. This probably is a question for their support. If you want more help here you probably need to demonstrate the problem, which could be slightly tricky, so I'd try support first.

Answer (score 0):

In CloudBerry Explorer, Sync functionality is exactly the same for PRO and freeware product. You may try CloudBerry backup and find out if it works for your purposes. Please note that it will run a backup job, which will work in one direction. CloudBerry backup has 15-day free trial so feel free to check.